# What does 'Future' mean as an extrinsic's result status?

Tags: polkadot-js, extrinsicstatus

I am expecting `result.status.isFinalized` for a `balances.transfer` call but within the result callback I get `status: 'Future'` and nothing else. What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ded44948e2d5a398abcb4e342b0513cb690961bb/primitives/runtime/src/transaction_validity.rs#L44-L45), this transaction validity status is returned when the nonce of the transaction is higher than the expected one taken from the current storage.